# How to find mongodb server ip

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating a MERN stack app. Right now I need to get the MongoDB server IP. They suggest using nslookup tools to get the IP address. Can anyone suggest me how to do that?
What thing should be added after nslookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your mongodb server cluster URI after it.

Example:

```
nslookup ds-shard-00-00-17jcm.mongodb-dev.net
```

Here is more information:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/faq/networking/

Comment: I tried but it is showing a non-authoritative answer: Can't find cluster***
can you help me in this?

Comment: Found solution in this doc- https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-connection-test-dns-name-does-not-exist/86048/3

Comment: If you think my solution helped,  accept it otherwise other people might answer it too after it has already been answered :)